# How to prevent laravel changing folder owner

Tags: laravel, apache, filesystems, chown

Now and then we face a destructive issue within a Laravel project:

Storage log file

```
production.ERROR: Unable to create lockable file: /var/www/html/storage/framework/cache/data/... Please ensure you have permission to creto create files in this location.
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/LockableFile.php(43)
```

When the issue happens `ls -l` gives

```
drwxrwsr-x+   2 apache   apache     4096 Sep  2 14:36 logs
```

To solve the issue we run `sudo chown -R ec2-user:apache logs/` which gives

```
drwxrwsr-x+   2 ec2-user   apache     4096 Sep  2 14:36 logs
```

But this is a manual fix...

Therefore, I would like to ask:

A) **How to prevent the file system suddenly changing owner** which breaks the coding?

B) Alternatively how to trigger production error notifications within a Laravel project to be warned about such issues?

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your second query, you can use either of them for error reporting:

1. [sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-laravel)
2. [flare](https://flareapp.io/)
3. [busnag](https://www.bugsnag.com/)

All the exceptions are handled by **App\Exceptions\Handler** class and in this class, there is a method named **register** you can configure any of the above tools in there so that exceptions can be reported there. Else you can build your custom report method like sending an email to you with an exception message or sending a slack notification.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue permanently you have to give the right permission in the code so go to `config/logging.php` you will find something like below:

```
    'channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['daily'],
        'ignore_exceptions' => false,
    ],

    'single' => [
        'driver' => 'single',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
    ],

    'daily' => [
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
        'days' => 14,
    ],

    ...

],
```

add `'permission' => 0775,` to the channels used, so it will be like below (I have added it to `single` and `daily` channels):

```
    'channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['daily'],
        'ignore_exceptions' => false,
    ],

    'single' => [
        'driver' => 'single',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
        'permission' => 0775,
    ],

    'daily' => [
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
        'days' => 14,
        'permission' => 0775,
    ],

    ...

],
```

This fix Tested on Laravel 6

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I applied your change. Now suddenly this error was back. It is the folder `storage/logs/framework` causing issues. So I will add `'permission' => 0775` to file stores in the file `config/cache.php`. Hopefully it won't return this way...